# HTML jQuery change paragraphs on a button click

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, onclick

I am making a simple website that has a main text window with just text on it. I would like to have buttons like Home, About, Contact etc. Now, I don't want to make about.html, contact.html etc but I would rather just change the text without loading a new page? (so it feels more smooth).

So I made couple of paragraphs with text suited for each page (home, about etc.), now is there a way for what I'm asking you? To just change the paragraph on click of a button? Or is there any simple way of doing this without making the .html files for each page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you are looking for is making content replacement with Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree with tvanfosson and recommend something like UI tabs or AJAX loading, but if you want to see a very rudimentary way you can do it with jQuery hide/show:

http://jsfiddle.net/ADDPH/7/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="index">Index</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="other">Other</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="index hide">This is the home page.</div>
        <div class="contact hide" style="display:none;">This is my contact info.</div>
        <div class="other hide" style="display:none;">This is other stuff.</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

jQuery

```
$("#nav a").click( function() {
    $(".hide").hide(); // hide other divs, marked with hide class
    var c = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0]; //Get First Class
    $("#content ."+c).show(); //show anything inside content div with the class c (marked with a . to represent class)
});​
```

Comment: I should clarify, I broke several good programming techniques as far as CSS and stuff like that went, but that is the basic functionality.

Comment: This is what I wanted! Thank you all for jqueri UI suggestions, I'll sure look into that as it looks simple enough. Just tell me one thing - do i need to input both jqueries then (into html file)? Or is this just a modified buffed jquery type? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) plugin, which will do exactly what you want if you place the content inline.  Alternatively, you can have separate content files, but load them via AJAX using the same plugin. Even if you decide not to use the plugin you can achieve the same effect with a similar technique of hiding all but the main "tab" on page load, then using anchors on your divs with suitable hrefs on your buttons to allow you to determine which tab to show.

The [jQuery UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) is another method for handling multiple content sections per page.

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery Ui Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) and 
[jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/).

it is very easy with jQuery UI accordion.

[jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

[jQuery Ui Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you store the data in memory (in a variable or something) and then bind the click event to a function that changes a div?